# Improve search when doing joins. Cluster tables?

Tags: oracle, join, oracle11g, normalization

Say we have three tables:
-Buildings
-Rooms
-People

A building can have from 1 to 30 rooms (let say average is 3)
And a building can have from 0 to 30 people (average 3 again)
A room and a person can only belong to a single Building.

Every month we add around 50.000 new Buildings to our database with their rooms and people.
We could drop data that is older than 2 years so we will have around 1.2M Buildings rows.

Main problem is that we want to search and return data that usually(but not always) includes at least two tables(Buildings always present) so we will have to perform joins.

I studied 3 solutions.

- Having normalized data (Low performance due to joins and low scalability)
- Replicate building data in Rooms and People table. (Fast but I don't generally like denormalization)
- Oracle Cluster Tables. (Seems to provide good performance and data is still normalized)

So question is:
Is Oracle Cluster suitable for this situation?
Is it OK to continuously add rows to such an Cluster?
If you don't recommend Cluster, why and what would suit better?

Details:

Cluster:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT *
    /*+ FIRST_ROWS(200)*/
  FROM BUILDING_C R
  INNER JOIN PEOPLE_C C
  ON (R.BUILDING_id = C.BUILDING_id)  
  INNER JOIN ROOM_C S
  ON (S.BUILDING_id = R.BUILDING_id)
  WHERE S.OPEN_DATE               >= SYSDATE - 60 -1
  AND S.OPEN_DATE               <= SYSDATE - 60
  ORDER BY S.OPEN_DATE
  )
WHERE rownum < 200;--17 consistent gets
```

[image: Autotrace output]

Normalized:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT *
    /*+ FIRST_ROWS(200)*/
  FROM BUILDING_N R
  INNER JOIN PEOPLE_N C
  ON (R.BUILDING_id = C.BUILDING_id)  
  INNER JOIN ROOM_N S
  ON (S.BUILDING_id = R.BUILDING_id)
  WHERE S.OPEN_DATE               >= SYSDATE - 60 -1
  AND S.OPEN_DATE               <= SYSDATE - 60
  ORDER BY S.OPEN_DATE
  )
WHERE rownum < 200;--44 consistent gets
```

[image: Autotrace Output]

Comment: Denormalization is not evil. Sometimes it is a must. You can consider clustered tables as being denormalized on physical level. The volumes you mention are too huge - 1M of rows is not too much for Oracle. Clustering is usually used for tables which can not "live" independently, i.e. which much be joined with something else to have some meaning. Also beware that some old-school DBA do not like clustered tables, as there were some problems with them in the past.

Comment: Have you investigated the execution plans you're getting for your 'low performance' queries? Joins are intrinsic so it seems odd that you're saying they are a problem. Do you have suitable indexes for the joins you are making, including on foreign keys? Without seeing the schema, data, queries and plans it's hard to guess why it might be slower than you expect.

Comment: I agree with the commenters above. Investigate the execution plans. What is wrong with them? Are you using properly indexed tables? Have you considered using Bitmap Join Indexes (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/indexes.htm#CIHGAFFF)? Also, how up-to-date do you need the data? Would a Materialized View work for denormalized representation?

Comment: Since there is a lot of data and we need just the first 200 I assumed that the best Execution plan is a nested loop. What is happening in all cases. About the indexes, yes they are created. Problem arise from the situation when you need to filter on data located in two different tables. About how "up-to-date" it wont be a problem to have 2 o 3 seconds of replication process. And yes, Materialized views may solve the problem but I cannot use them (Forbiden by management) :)

Comment: It would probably help if you showed the tables, indexes and sample queries. Are you just assuming what the plan should be or have you looked at it - and can you add that too? And are your statistics up-to-date? It's hard to tell if you're just doing something odd.

Comment: Up to date statistics, using the index I want to use. Execution plans are for denormalized: Search by index, retrieve and filter. For Normalized: Search by index, retrieve, filter, if ok, with join index retrieve in the other table, filter and if ok retrieve.

Comment: On any semi-decent server 50ms for a 3 table join against tables this small should be easily achievable. It sounds as though your question isn't about your problem but your proposed solution. If you actually ask a question about your exact problem then I'm sure someone will be able to help easily. Include table structures, queries and explain plans as a minimum as well as sample data. As it stands you're only going to get generic answers telling you to use materialized views or add indexes. It's better to be specific...

Comment: @Ben Question edited with further data. I did not provided further info because I did not wanted to make the question too complex so it was easy to read.

Comment: You indicate your performance drops radically when joining tables. Is this degradation on production class hardware, or a test environment. The data size is, as noted many times, so small that the data should all be in memory and only really pathological execution plans would botch it so badly that the performance in unacceptable.

Comment: @Pekka it is in a test system, in production we'll have better hardware but much more data as well so we cannot fully rely in the cache. I am performing some further benchmarks and looks like it might suit the normalize version without cluster with some little improvements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Clustering** is a method of storing tables that are intimately related and often joined together into the same area on disk. The cluster key is the column or columns by which the tables are usually joined in a query to save on IO. But, if the combined size of all the table rows in a single Cluster Row will exceed the size of a disk block then you will end up at chaining and one day, you loose all the advantages of cluster. In my opinion, better to avoid since it will be a overhead considering that you have a rolling volume of 1.2 M with all 3 tables in a cluster which would obviously have an impact of HWM.

**Better go for JOINS.**

For example.

```
CREATE TABLE BUILDING_C ( BUILDING_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
                     ADDRESS_FIELD VARCHAR2 ( 25 ) );

CREATE TABLE PEOPLE_C ( BUILDING_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
                    CUSTOMER_ID NUMBER,
                    ROOM_ID NUMBER,
                    CUSTOMER_DETAILS VARCHAR2 ( 25 ) );

CREATE TABLE ROOM_C ( BUILDING_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
                  ROOM_ID NUMBER,
                  OPEN_DATE DATE,
                  CURRENT_OCCUPANCY CHAR ( 1 ) );

BEGIN
    DBMS_STATS.SET_TABLE_STATS ( OWNNAME     => 'REALSPIRITUALS',
                            TABNAME  => 'BUILDING_C',
                            NUMROWS  => 20000000 );
END;
/

BEGIN
    DBMS_STATS.SET_TABLE_STATS ( OWNNAME     => 'REALSPIRITUALS',
                            TABNAME  => 'PEOPLE_C',
                            NUMROWS  => 20000000 );
END;
/

BEGIN
    DBMS_STATS.SET_TABLE_STATS ( OWNNAME     => 'REALSPIRITUALS',
                            TABNAME  => 'ROOM_C',
                            NUMROWS  => 20000000 );
END;
/
```

In your query, your hint will not be taking into effect since you have used `SELECT * /*+ FIRST_ROWS(200)*/` instead of `SELECT /*+ FIRST_ROWS(200)*/ *` So you end up in OPTIMIZER MODE=ALL_ROWS rather than OPTIMIZER MODE=FIRST_ROWS

```
SET AUTOTRACE ON

SELECT
      *
FROM
      (SELECT
            /*+ FIRST_ROWS(200)*/
            *
       FROM
            BUILDING_C R
            INNER JOIN PEOPLE_C C
                ON ( R.BUILDING_ID = C.BUILDING_ID )
            INNER JOIN ROOM_C S
                ON ( S.BUILDING_ID = R.BUILDING_ID )
       WHERE
            S.OPEN_DATE >=   SYSDATE - 60 - 1
            AND S.OPEN_DATE <= SYSDATE - 60
       ORDER BY
            S.OPEN_DATE)
WHERE
      ROWNUM < 200;


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
   0       SELECT STATEMENT Optimizer Mode=HINT: FIRST_ROWS (Cost=54189 Card=199 Bytes=38 K)
   1    0    COUNT STOPKEY
   2    1      VIEW (Cost=54189 Card=50 K Bytes=9 M)
   3    2        SORT ORDER BY STOPKEY (Cost=54189 Card=50 K Bytes=9 M)
   4    3          FILTER
   5    4            NESTED LOOPS
   6    5              NESTED LOOPS (Cost=52041 Card=50 K Bytes=9 M)
   7    6                MERGE JOIN (Cost=2020 Card=50 K Bytes=5 M)
   8    7                  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID REALSPIRITUALS.BUILDING_C (Cost=826 Card=20 M Bytes=1G)
   9    8                    INDEX FULL SCAN REALSPIRITUALS.SYS_C00504893 (Cost=26 Card=20 M)
  10    7                  SORT JOIN (Cost=1194 Card=50 K Bytes=1 M)
  11   10                    TABLE ACCESS FULL REALSPIRITUALS.ROOM_C (Cost=660 Card=50 K Bytes=1 M)
  12    6                INDEX UNIQUE SCAN REALSPIRITUALS.SYS_C00504894 (Cost=0 Card=1)
  13    5              TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID REALSPIRITUALS.PEOPLE_C (Cost=1 Card=1 Bytes=91)

Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          1  recursive calls
          0  spare statistic 3
          0  gcs messages sent
          0  db block gets from cache
          0  physical reads direct (lob)
          0  queue position update
          0  queue single row
          0  queue ocp pages
          0  HSC OLTP Compressed Blocks
          0  HSC IDL Compressed Blocks
          0  rows processed
```

**Suggestions:**

1. Use index on OPEN_DATE column
2. Use parallel hint if needed to speed up /*+ parallel (table,n) */
3. Try range partitions

Answer (score 3):

You say "improve search", but, have you actually implemented this data model?  Have you tried some candidate queries?  Are they not performing adequately?  1.2 million rows is peanuts for Oracle.  I have several tables with billions of rows.  I know someone who has a partitioned IOT with over 5 *trillion* rows.

First, normalize everything, and test out some candidate queries.  How are they performing?  If you have problems, are you missing any indexes?  What do you consider adequate performance?

Based on what I have read, I would be very surprised if you couldn't get satisfactory performance from a normalized data model, with a correct set of indexes.

Comment: I did implemented it in the three ways and benchmarked it. Target performance is no more than 50ms to do the searches.

Comment: Everything fits the bill(under 50ms) until I need to search using data from two tables. Then, denormalized and clustered maintain the same times(it might rises some ms but not much) but normalized solution goes to 200 ms. I believe it is because it needs to perform two IOs to check if the row combination of the two table is ok or not.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the SQL, the execution plan, and the table and index definitions for the underperforming SQL.